# Equivalence of two expressions involving the derivative of the exponential map

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-equations

While working on a problem involving the [derivative of the exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map), I came across an interesting identity that seems to be true but I can't prove it. Here is the identity:

$$\frac\partial{\partial A}\mathrm{tr}\left(S\exp(A)\right)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac d{dt}\left[\exp(A+tS)\right]$$
where $S$ is a symmetrical definite-positive $n\times n$ matrix, $A$ is a symmetrical $n\times n$ matrix, and $t\in\mathbb{R}$. The function $\exp$ is the usual [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential). The function $\mathrm{tr}$ is the usual [matrix trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)). All matrices are restricted to real numbers.

Is there a straightforward argument why these two expressions are the same? In this, the matrices $A$ and $S$ are not expected to commute, i.e.: $AS\ne SA$. This implies in particular that $S\exp(A)\ne\exp(A)S$.

Using [Duhamel's formula](https://mathoverflow.net/a/403404/468380), I can write that:
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac d{dt}\left[\exp(A+tS)\right]=\int_0^1\exp(\tau A)S\exp((1-\tau)A)d\tau$$
but I have no idea yet how to simplify the other part of the identity. I can show that:
$$\frac\partial{\partial A}\mathrm{tr}(\exp(A))=\exp(A)$$
but adding the (non-commuting) $S$ inside the trace makes a direct generalization difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=\o}^\infty}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^k}
\def\Skj{\Sk\Sj}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\k{\frac{\o}{k!}}
\def\c#1{\color{\red}{#1}}
$Define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
B &= A+St \qiq \dot B = S \\
F &= \exp(B) \;=\; I + \Sk\k\:B^k \\
}$$
then use differentials to calculate the derivative of $F$
$$\eqalign{
dF &= \Sk\k\:\c{dB^k} \\
 &= \Sk\k\c{\Sj\LR{B^{k-j}\:dB\:B^{j-\o}}} \\
\dot F &= {\Skj\k\LR{B^{k-j}SB^{j-\o}}} \\
\lim_{t\to 0}\dot F
 &= \Skj\k\LR{A^{k-j}SA^{j-\o}} \\
}$$
Now consider the gradient of the trace expression
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= S:e^A \\
 &= S:\LR{I+\Sk\k A^k} \\
d\phi &= S:\LR{\Sk\k\:dA^k} \\
 &= S:\LR{\Sk\k\Sj A^{k-j}\:dA\:A^{j-\o}} \\
 &= \LR{\Skj\k\LR{A^{k-j}SA^{j-\o}}}:dA \\
\grad{\phi}{A}
 &= \Skj\k\LR{A^{k-j}SA^{j-\o}} \\
}$$

---

The above derivation uses the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$